# Are Kanji acronyms ever used?

Tags: word-choice

I have seen NTT, OPEC, DIY, NHK, etc. used but are there any Kanji acronyms commonly used?

Comment: There too many to write down.

Comment: A thing to note is that in kanji acronyms, the readings of the kanji sometimes change, especially if the original word has jukujikun readings of kanji. The acronyms are usually read according to on'yomi - e.g., 早稲田(わせだ)大学 becomes 早(そう)大

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are hundreds and perhaps thousands of those, so it would be almost unnatural to list just a few here.  Instead, I am posting a good link I have found.

http://a.yourpedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E7%95%A5%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking like 漢検 for the 漢字検定.  I guess that counts.